# I need to modify this powershell code to change the Windows scaling of only my primary monitor and not all monitors

Tags: windows, powershell, display, scaling, monitor

I found this code to change Windows scaling when I launch a game, and change it back after I close the program. It works fine; however, it changes the scaling of both monitors, and I would like it to only change my primary monitor. Any ideas?

```
function Set-Scaling {
    # Posted by IanXue-MSFT on
    # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197944/batch-file-or-tool-like-powertoy-to-change-the-res.html
    # $scaling = 0 : 100% (default)
    # $scaling = 1 : 125% 
    # $scaling = 2 : 150% 
    # $scaling = 3 : 175% 
    param($scaling)
    $source = @'
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SystemParametersInfo")]
    public static extern bool SystemParametersInfo(
                      uint uiAction,
                      uint uiParam,
                      uint pvParam,
                      uint fWinIni);
'@
    $apicall = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $source -Name WinAPICall -Namespace SystemParamInfo -PassThru
    $apicall::SystemParametersInfo(0x009F, $scaling, $null, 1) | Out-Null
}

Set-Scaling -scaling 0

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

cmd.exe /c start steam://rungameid/381210

Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

Wait-Process -Name DeadByDaylight-Win64-Shipping

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

Set-Scaling -scaling 2
```